# Leaderboard Facebook Score Api Swift

Tags: swift, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, leaderboard

I'm a new developer and have been trying to find a swift 3 tutorial for how to create a leaderboard based on Facebook's Score API - without any result.

I only find their own documentation, not in swift and I can't understand any of the process. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements

Is there any good tutorials on the subject or how should I learn how to create a leaderboard in my simple game with Facebook? The documentation above seems impossible to me as a beginner.

Thank you for helping a newbie.